# How to combine gwt and php?

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does GWT support php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183743/does-gwt-support-php)

I'm new to GWT - in fact, I'm just reviewing it to see if it meets my needs.  First of all, the starter doc on it is incorrect in a lot of places but i digress...My question is if i create a simple UI using GWT and generate js/html with it, can i easily embed php into it?

For example, if i manually insert the php code after i generate the html/js from gwt, then i make a change to the gwt project, i'd have to redo the php coding.  Is there a good way to do this automatically?  Should i not be using php to begin with?  Any direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GWT code is compiled into JavaScript, and runs completely on the client-side in the browser.  You can't execute PHP code in the browser, so that is a no-go, but you can have the GWT application communicate with the PHP code on the server.

For example, a mail client like GMail is a JavaScript application that runs in the browser, but when you click a mail item to read it the client needs to contact the server to get the text of the email so that it can be displayed.

So the short answer is that no, you can't insert PHP code into your GWT application, but you can have a GWT app running in the browser communicate (via XHR) with a PHP application on the server.